# RoboSpice - getting started not working

Tags: android, onresume, onpause, robospice

I managed to implement sample of robospice (GoogleHttpClientSpiceService) and it works - it successfully goes to server, gets data and stores it in cache. Even displays toast and updates GUI if Activity is not onPause.

My problem (and only reason I tried robospice) is that if Activity is resumed, it doesn't get notified again. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    @Override //THIS IS NOT CALLED ON ACTIVITY RESUME (BECAUSE OF THIS I CANNOT DISMISS DIALOG)
    public void onRequestSuccess( final String result ) {
        Toast.makeText( PrijavaActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        Log.w(TAG, "sakses" + result);


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("prijavaDialog");
        if(fragment!=null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood RoboSpice. The behavior you get is the right one.

When an activity is stopped (inactive as you said) then all of its requests listeners are removed, they won't be notified.

Listeners are only notified as long as the activity than owns them is still alive. That's the whole point of RoboSpice : to prevent memory leaks of listeners or activities.

If you want to "go on listening" the result of a request  even when the activity that launched it has gone inactive, then you must adopt a different strategy. You should use a more stable context like the application or a service and launch your request form it or maybe just listen to the request result from that context (using addListenerIfPending, not execute).